# Linear transformation with given spectrum

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $V$ be a complex vector space. Let $A$ be a linear transformation such that $\sigma (A)=\left \{ 5,6 \right \}$.Prove that $(A-5I)^{n-1}\circ (A-6I)^{n-1}=O$, where $n = dim(V)$.

No idea how to start. Any hint is welcome.

Comment: What can the characteristic polynomial of $A$ be ?

Comment: I suppose that by $O$ you meant $0$.

Comment: by $O$ I meant zero operator